Перенос строки и отступы vscode
Пример: пишу код на пайтон в vscode на mac, вот у меня фрагмент кода с отступом, далее жму enter строка переводиться на новую с тем же отступом, в pycharm есть такая вещь что если нажать shift+enter то перевод на следующую строку будет произведен без отступов (т.е. с начала строки), так же есть опция перевести строку с уменьшением отступа на один уровень.
Не удается найти какая настройка в vscode отвечает за подобные горячие клавиши?
